# Layered parallax scrolling?

Tags: javascript, scroll, parallax, layered

I'm trying to create a dynamic background for my website which has a solid colour background with an image layered over the top (of a flag) that parallaxes so that it scrolls at a different rate to the page.

Does anyone have any projects they can suggest that would allow me to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Resource recommendations are off-topic for SO. But if you have a specific coding question we can help you with that.

Comment: Try searching github for parallax! There are some projects that could help & inspire you.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a couple of pages with parallax using this guide. http://untame.net/2013/04/how-to-integrate-simple-parallax-with-twitter-bootstrap/